# Azure IoT Hub - check if port 5671 is opened

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I want to test connection with Azure IoTHub: I have added a firewall rule to stop all the traffic for port 5671 (IoT AMQP) and I have a test connection method that I am expecting to fail in this case.

```
using (var deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create(iotHubUrl, authenticationMethod))
{
    try
    {
        await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(encodedMessage);

        var receivedMessage = await deviceClient.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        if (receivedMessage != null)
        {
            await deviceClient.CompleteAsync(receivedMessage);
            return true;
        }

        await deviceClient.CloseAsync();
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger?.LogDebug($"Failed : {ex.Message}");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I get the receivedMessage and everything looks ok, but in IoT hub logs, I see the **deliveryCountExceeded** error.

Any other method to use here?

Answer (score 0):

To check Azure IoT connectivity status you could use [ConnectionStatusChangesHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.connectionstatuschangeshandler?view=azure-dotnet).

DeviceClient will use the default retry policy which is set to retry for 4 minutes before any of the async I/O operations will throw the exception.